# Dynamics of pairwise distances in the $n$-body problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Consider the $n$-body problem where we are interested in describing the time evolution of $n$ masses interacting through a potential $U$. Let $D$ be the matrix containing all pairwise distances between our masses; i.e. $$D_{ij} = \sqrt{(x_i - x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2 + (z_i - z_j)^2}$$ where $x_i, y_i, z_i$ are the Cartesian coordinates of the $i$'th mass. Assume that $U$ only depends on $D$, and not individual positions. [1]

I am interested in finding a differential equation that describes the time evolution of $D$, without individual positions appearing in it. Can we formulate such an equation in classical mechanics?

[1] This is indeed true for Newton's Law of Gravitation, but it need not hold for a generic potential.

Comment: Sure, the Euler-Lagrange equation with $D_{ij}$ as your generalised coordinates.

Comment: @lemon: I actually thought about this before, but I wasn't sure how it would work. There are two issues I can't get around: (1) Generalized coordinates need to uniquely determine individual positions, no? Our $D_{ij}$ do not have this property. (2) Independent of the first issue, how to express _Kinetic Energy_ in terms of expressions like $\partial D_{ij} / \partial t$ is not obvious to me. I tried to do this, but I quickly ran into terms like $\partial \mathbf{r}_k / \partial D_{ij}$, which did not let me get rid of positions, completely.

Answer (score 1):

From the equations $\dot q = p/m$ and $\dot p=V'(q)$ and the definition $Q=D(q)$ you can derive by differentiation $m\dot Q=D'(q)p$ and $\ddot m^2Q=D''(q)pp-mD'(q)V'(q)$, where $m$ is a diagonal matrix of masses. The second equation produces an ODE for $Q$ if you can express $p$ in terms of $\dot Q$ up to terms in the null space of $D''(q)$ (i.e., translation and rotation degrees of freedom). This should be possible from the first equation, which is drastically underdetermined, hence should have many solutions.

For actually doing it I would first try (but I am too lazy to do it) the $k$-particle case for $k=2,3,4$ to see whether a nice formula exists. The case $k=4$ should already be general enough to guess the formula for general $k$.

Comment: Hello Prof. Neumaier. I would like to explore the approach you suggested, and see where it leads to. I might ask for clarifications soon. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @iheap: I noticed that I had missed some factors of $m$; now corrected.

Comment: Hello Prof. Neumaier! It has been almost a year since you suggested a possible way to settle this question. I have tried following your advice for the $k = 3$ case, but to no success. Would you be open to collaborating with me on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: @iheap: it is probably easier to derive differential equations for the $c_{ij}=D_{ij}^2$. This gets rid of all square roots and simplifies all computations. At the end one can convert the differential equations to one for the distances themselves. If you still cannot handle this squared version, pose the (squared) problem with your partial results on https://www.physicsoverflow.org , where (unlike here) unrestricted discussion is possible, and I'll guide you there.